# Initialize multiple rngs in a single program

Tags: c++, random

I want to use multiple RNGs in my C++ application using `<random>`. What is the best way to seed them? I fear that the random numbers from different RNGs will be correlated too much when seeding each RNG with a random number from a single RNG.

Comment: Each call to `rand` uses the same PRNG, so seed once and use where ever you want in your application.

Comment: I will not use rand but RNGs defined in `<random>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is your concern, I would suggest to use `random_device` to seed all of the RNGs. Output from `random_device` is as near to true randomness as you can practically get.

(Well I suppose it's debatable but it's the best the standard library is going to give you in a cross-platform fashion. A possibly even more reliably random alternative would be to pull seeds from www.random.org or something.)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/random_device/

That's only in C++11, if you are on an earlier standard, you can use `boost::random_device` instead.

Comment: If `random_device` uses something like `/dev/random` then the entropy pool is exhausted after the first call.

Comment: That depends on how much randomness he pulls for his seeds. If he just wants to initialize a handful of `std::mt19937`'s , then `/dev/random` contains plenty of randomness for that. Using `random_device` to generate seeds is the standard advice though, you can't say it won't work without more info.